# Xquery remove element

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<informacao xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="informacao.xsd">
    <num_individuos>2</num_individuos>
    <morada>
        <pais>Portugal</pais>
        <cidade_origem>Penafiel</cidade_origem>
    </morada>
    <pessoas>
        <pessoa>
            <nome>pessoa1</nome>
            <data_nascimento>2021-12-29</data_nascimento>
        </pessoa>
        <pessoa>
            <nome>pessoa2</nome>
            <data_nascimento>2021-12-29</data_nascimento>
        </pessoa>
    </pessoas>
    <preferencia_dias>
        <dia>2021-09-16</dia>
        <dia>2021-09-17</dia>
        <dia>2021-09-18</dia>
    </preferencia_dias>
</informacao>
```

And the following DB:
[Basex DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9sqo.png)

I want to keep the  elements if the count on the db of the same day is less than 2 or if they dont are on the db.

Based on that the result would be:
`<preferencia_dias> <dia>2021-09-18</dia> </preferencia_dias>`

EDIT:
Code developed:

```
declare function page:filter_counterDays($days){
  
  for $pub in distinct-values(db:open("visitas")//data)
  order by  $pub ascending
     let $count := count(db:open("visitas")//data[. eq $pub])
    
 

for $day at $pos in $days//dia
order  by $day ascending
return if (($day eq $pub))then(
 if($count=2)then(
 remove($days//dia,$pos)
 )else()
)else(
  
)

};
```

This code is only working properly if only have 2 elements , I know tested with 3 and the result ends up being

```
<dia>2021-09-17</dia>
<dia>2021-09-18</dia>
<dia>2021-09-16</dia>
<dia>2021-09-18</dia>
```

Instead of `<dia>2021-09-18</dia>`

Comment: Have you tried to adapt the answer to your previous, similar question? Show us what you have tried and tell us how/where it failed.

Comment: Done, I just edited my question with the code I have

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
declare function local:filter_counterDays($days){ 
  let $pubs := for $data in db:open("visitas")//data
               group by $pub := $data
               where count($data) lt 2
               return $pub
  return (
   copy $mdays := $days
   modify delete node $mdays//dia[. = $pubs]
   return $mdays//dia
  )
};
```

Comment: Well, that for sure worked as it should. Thanks